# How to determine if SearchPattern effects extension of file?

Tags: c#, regex, directory

I'm currently working with the `Directory`-class from .NET
and I'd like to know whether a SearchPattern is defining an extension or not.

For example: If I pass "hello_world" as a pattern to the `GetFiles`-Method, I clearly don't mention an extension.

If I pass  * . *  to this method, all extensions are allowed. If I pass "*.docx" to it, all docx-files are allowed.

How am I sure to get the extension out of a search pattern?

Does `searchPattern.Split('.').LastOrDefault()` ***always*** contain **only** the extension - if an extension is declared or are there cases in which the searchPattern allows for different things and so this solution could get me into some troubles?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could think of search patterns like "..\xyz" or ".\xyz" where your method won't work as expected. The first case is not allowed by the implementation though (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx at the description of the parameter `searchPattern`). I don't know if the second case is valid.

Beside that only * and ? are wildcards, while all other characters are as-is. I can not think of another search pattern where your method won't return an extension.

Comment: Maybe I confused u a bit - I don't want to know the "resutl" of my searchpattern. I just want to know, if the search pattern is somehow requesting an extension such as .* or .docx or any other extension. Like u said ..\xyz seems to be valid and does not request a specific extension as everything in xyz is allowed. Therefore my "desired" method would return null. If you pass *.doc my method should return ".doc" if you pass .* my method should return ".*"

Comment: If it's an extension there must be a dot following only letters, digits or wildcards (* or ?) and in front of the dot there can be no path separator (\ or /). If you check this you can ensure that it is an extension.

Comment: A tip: Search patterns with a 3-character-extension in combination with the asterisk may also find extensions with more characters. E.g. the search pattern "*.abc" will also find "xyz.abcd". This is only true if the extension in the search pattern has a length of 3 and only if the asterisk is used (the question mark will work as expected). This can be a problem when parsing extensions as well.